# A problem on the proof of a lemma of commutative algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Lemma 10. Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $\mathfrak a$ an ideal in $R$ of height $\mathrm{ht}\,\mathfrak a = r$. Assume there are elements $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{s-1}\in \mathfrak a$ such that $\mathrm{ht}(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{s-1})= s-1$ for some $s\in\mathbb{N}$ where $1 \le s \le r$. Then there exists an element $a_s\in\mathfrak a$ such that $\mathrm{ht}\, (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_s)= s$.

> *Proof.* Consider elements $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{s-1}\in \mathfrak a$, $1 \le s \le r$, such that $\mathrm{ht}(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{s-1})= s-1$, and let $\mathfrak p_1,\mathfrak p_2,\dots,\mathfrak p_n\subset R$ be the minimal prime divisors of $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{s-1})$. Then, using Krull’s Dimension Theorem, we have $\mathrm{ht}\,\mathfrak p_i\le s-1<r$ for all $i$.  Since $\mathrm{ht}\,\mathfrak a=r$, this implies a $\mathfrak a\not\subset \mathfrak p_i$ for all $i$ and, hence, $\mathfrak a\,\not \subset \cup_{i=1}^n\,\mathfrak p_i$ by 1.3/7. Thus, choosing $a_s\in \mathfrak a-\cup_{i=1}^n\,\mathfrak p_i$, we get
> $\mathrm{ht}(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_s)\ge s$ and, in fact $\mathrm{ht}\,(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_s)= s$ by Krull’s Dimension Theorem.

This Lemma comes from Siegfried Bosch's book *Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*, section 2.4, Lemma 10, page 77. I don't understand why we obtain $\mathrm{ht}(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_s)\ge s$ from $\mathrm{ht}(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{s-1})= s-1$. I can only get $\mathrm{ht}(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_s)\ge s-1$ due to $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{s-1})\subset (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{s})$.

Could you show me the proof of this point? Thanks very much!

Comment: Please do not use images; [here is a detailed explanation of why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). The site has excellent typesetting capabilities, as you know since you used MathJax in the rest of the question, so please type up the text and remove the image link.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, I will.

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{ht}(a_1,\cdots, a_s)=\min \operatorname{ht} \mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal containing $(a_1,\cdots, a_s).$

If $\operatorname{ht}(a_1,\cdots, a_s)<s$, then there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ containing $(a_1,\cdots, a_s)$ such that $\operatorname{ht} \mathfrak{p}\leq s-1<s$.

Hence $\mathfrak{p}$ is one of the $\mathfrak{p}_i$'s. But that implies $(a_1,\cdots, a_s)\subset \mathfrak{p}\subset \cup_i \mathfrak{p}_i$, hence $a_s\in \cup_i \mathfrak{p}_i$, a contradiction. Thus, $\operatorname{ht}(a_1,\cdots, a_s)\geq s$.